# How to update residential addresses registered with SCHUFA?

Tags: germany, credit-history

I just received my currently dated SCHUFA credit report, however, my residential address is not current.

My understanding was that when you, as a German resident, open up a bank account, they push an update to SCHUFA with your new address.

I tried calling them, but as I don't speak German, it wasn't really helpful. So, how can I change my address registered with SCHUFA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've contacted them over email at **meineschufa@schufa.de** and explained it in English, also I've provided an [automated German translation](https://deepl.com).

They then asked me for my address registration certificate, in German of course. I've provided it over email and after 2 weeks I received a confirmation letter as well as a free report in my postbox confirming that the address has been changed.

I have also changed my legal name during the process.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, when you register yourself (and people that lives with you) in the Town Hall of your neighbourhood, the Finanzamt is also updated, and this last one has some partnership with SCHUFA. So SCHUFA database *should* be updated automatically.

However, there are some Schufa partners that the Town Hall doesn't communicate to, and your address may be wrong, affecting some Banks also (because SCHUFA couldn't validated properly your address). So I recommend you after registering yourself in the Town Hall, send the letter you received from them to dokumente@schufa.de asking to update your address on their databases.

Normally this process takes 1 full week.